# MSSQL: WHERE Field Does Not Equal List of Strings

Tags: python, sql-server, list, filter, conditional-statements

------------UPDATED______________

I want to remove rows of a data table if column A is equal to a list of strings.  I am able to do this in Python code but don't know how to do it in MSSQL.

The screenshot below shows a sample of the table I have vs. the table I want.  I want to remove the row if the value is between 4800 and 4900.  **Column A is comprised of all string values though.**

[image]

Please see my Python code below:

```
import numpy as np

df_adhoc_1_final['A'] = df_adhoc_1_final['A'].astype(str)

aircraft_num = np.arange(4888, 4903).astype(str)

for i in aircraft_num:
     df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[df_adhoc_1_final['A'].str.contains(i) == False]
```

Comment: I can probably help but you need to post some details. I am a sql server guy and can't even spell python correctly, let alone feel confident knowing what that code does.

Comment: sure ... If column A contains the string form of any number between 4888 and 4903 (4888 and 4903 inclusive), then filter out those rows from the table

Comment: Where YourColumn > 4888 and YourColumn < 4903???

Comment: I guess you mean `Where ColumnA NOT BETWEEN 4888 AND 4903` right ??

Comment: @Krishraj: yes, but those numbers are strings in my data table ... does that impact it?

Comment: I have a feeling it isn't quite that simple but we still have very little detail. Does that column contain numbers stored as strings? Help us out here and don't make us guess.

Comment: yes, that column is all strings

Comment: This is like pulling teeth. We can't read your mind or see your screen. Please post some sample data so we won't have to guess. Might take a look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Agree @SeanLange.. PineNuts0 - Please post some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: please see updated question with sample tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited for 'A' to be a string

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleid int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   A nvarchar(255) not null
,   value_ int not null
);


insert into @example (a, value_)

select '4000', 22 union all
select '4888', 44 union all
select '4895', 33 union all
select '4933', 11 union all
select '5000', 14;


select A
     , value_
  from @example
where cast(a as int) not between 4800 and 4900;
```

### result set:

```
A       Value_
4000    22
4933    11
5000    14
```

Comment: I would point out to the OP that storing numbers as strings causes us to create nonSARGable predicates like this one where we have to cast your value to another datatype. And I posted a fun read for you earlier, here is another one about between. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common Regardless, +1 from me.

Comment: I understand sargability - I think the result set is null or 0 for select cares from user where GAFs > 0; but I digress. I'm aware of the subtle-ness of between, I'm sure the Op will test and play with the code ... I do enjoy the links and I've been using eom function as well.

Comment: I assumed you did, my comment was intended for the OP. ;)